# Powering a SATA HDD using usb y cable

Tags: hard-drive, usb, sata

Can i use [This Sata and Sata Power To Usb Cable](http://www.amazon.in/ADMI-USB-2-0-SATA-Adapter/dp/B019Q917JS?tag=googinhydr18418-21&tag=googinkenshoo-21&ascsubtag=21c4e694-b726-4275-b0b3-6846ec875759) To connect my 60gb fujitsu 2.5" hdd (sata) in a Pc externally where i would connect one usb into PC and another in a samsung mobile charger adapter (that comes with galaxy s6 edge, the fast charger) will this power up my hdd and will it work fine ? i dont want to buy a adapter because i am going to use this hdd with my pi so i dont have much place for a adapter.

and will the converter (in the link) work with the 3.5" hdd (that is usually used in Desktops) because the size of the pins is the same !

Thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The second connector is for power only, it does not need to be a real USB port. A "standard" USB power supply works in this application, I don't see why using a Samsung Quick Charge unit would be any different. This cable will work find for a 2.5" drive, but is not compatible a 3.5" drive or any SATA device utilizing the 12v power rail.

Quick Charge does have multiple voltage levels, although handshaking and agreeing on higher voltages is required between the device and charger, some caution is required when connecting an unsupported device. Fir safety sake, I would recommend picking up an inexpensive generic 1A USB block power source (like the kind you find at convenience store checkouts) instead of the Samsung one, even though from a technical standpoint it should work fine.

This should work for a 2.5" SATA drive, which only use the 5v power rail. Most 3.5" SATA drives use both the 5v and 12v power rails. It sounds like you probably need a more universal kit, like [this as an example](http://www.amazon.in/iConnect-IDE-USB-Supports-5-25-Inch/dp/B015O44Q8S).

Comment: some forums tell 3.5" sata hdd require 12v input so , if samsung adapter works with 2.5" because it requires 5v will it work with 3.5" sata also (160gb only no chance of having more than 160gb)?

Comment: Your question was specific to a 2.5" SATA drive, which only use the 5v power rail (if the 3.5' portion was there initially, I missed it and will edit my answer). Most 3.5" SATA drives use both the 5v and 12v power rails, but you can get inexpensive SATA or MOLEX power supplies to power drives in this instance, they will not work off of USB power only.

Comment: so will the 12v power supply unit for sata power for 3.5" work with 2.5" ? wont it overvolt it ?

Comment: No, they are distinctly different connection points, but the adapter you referenced in your original question is specific to 2.5" drives, it will not work on 3.5" drives.  

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_ATA#Power_connectors

Comment: It sounds like you need a more universal option, something like this: http://www.amazon.in/iConnect-IDE-USB-Supports-5-25-Inch/dp/B015O44Q8S